# How can we upload a PDF file with Delphi REST components?

Tags: api, rest, delphi

I have an Azure function App that receives a file and store in Azure Blob. It works fine with Postman and Javascript. Now I want to send a PDF file with Delphi. Can anybody write a code example of how it should be done? I try with the following code and it fails.

```pascal
File2Send := TMemoryStream.Create;

RESTRequest2.body.ClearBody;

RESTRequest2.Params.Clear;

fname := <path to my PDF file>;

RESTClient2.BaseURL := <my URL>;

RESTRequest2.Method := rmPOST;

RESTRequest2.AddParameter('Code','p228Vpw79SJU4IXQR3JIchSQMsR/fQ==');

File2Send.LoadFromFile(fname);


RESTRequest2.body.add(File2Send,'multipart/form-data');

// RESTRequest2.Addbody(File2Send,ctNone);  // I even tested the following

RESTRequest2.Execute;

Addlog(RESTResponse2.Content);   //write the output in a memo
```

Comment: Please format the code and specify the error you are getting.

Comment: *it fails* is not a problem description unless you're more specific about what *fails* means. Please [edit] your question to explain what *fails* means. Do you get an error message? If so, what is that complete, exact message?

Comment: Hi. I get the following error:    Exception class EHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'.

Comment: It looks like you pass authentication information in `Code` parameter that you add using `RESTRequest2.AddParameter`. This method adds parameter of kind [`pkGETorPOST`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind) to the request meaning that it will become part of the query string or request body when executing the request depending on HTTP method. Since your method is `rmPOST`, the parameter will be transferred in request body. You need to check endpoint documentation whether this is the correct way to pass authentication information.

Comment: Since postman is working, check what you are sending using postman. Probably you are sending some headers (which are mostly used for authentication these days), which are missing or not correctly specified (like Peter said) in your Delphi request.

Comment: I am using the same code in different locations of the program and it works fine. The only difference is that in other cases the body is a JSON.ToString. But, I will try what you saying to see if it helps.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: as you are sending a PDF file as the message body, you might need to change the `contenttype` to `application/pdf`.